# Ubuntu 20.04: bcm13 specific wifi disappearing when driver changes, not working with other drivers

Tags: drivers, wireless, broadcom

Specific wifi connection not shown broadcom drivers nightmare

I have a broadcom bcm4313 pciid 4727 rev01. I'm using Ubuntu 20.04

Today, my home wifi was not showing from the wifi list. However, it showed on my other devices and I was seeing all the neighbors wifis.

It realised that if I uninstalled the "additional drivers" bcmwl-kernel-source and reboot the computer, the wifi was showing again. But wifi was horrible. I installed brcmsmac since it's the only driver working with my adapter.

Sadly, it still was horrible and lately I can't even use the wifi, i get the question mark icon and sometimes it cannot connect.

Note that I can still connect to all neighbors wifis and that only my wifi disappears when I change to additional drivers's driver.

I tried everything b43, wl, bcma, brcmsmac, etc.

Edit: lsmod

```
Module                  Size  Used by
rfcomm                 81920  4
ccm                    20480  6
cmac                   16384  3
algif_hash             16384  1
algif_skcipher         16384  1
af_alg                 32768  6 algif_hash,algif_skcipher
bnep                   28672  2
binfmt_misc            24576  1
snd_hda_codec_conexant    28672  1
nvidia_uvm            954368  0
intel_rapl_msr         20480  0
snd_hda_codec_generic   102400  1 snd_hda_codec_conexant
ledtrig_audio          16384  1 snd_hda_codec_generic
snd_hda_codec_hdmi     77824  5
intel_rapl_common      40960  1 intel_rapl_msr
x86_pkg_temp_thermal    20480  0
snd_hda_intel          53248  4
intel_powerclamp       20480  0
nvidia_drm             49152  2
snd_intel_dspcfg       28672  1 snd_hda_intel
snd_intel_sdw_acpi     20480  1 snd_intel_dspcfg
coretemp               24576  0
nls_iso8859_1          16384  2
crct10dif_pclmul       16384  1
nvidia_modeset       1056768  4 nvidia_drm
snd_hda_codec         163840  4 snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec_conexant,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel
ghash_clmulni_intel    16384  0
snd_hda_core          110592  5 snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec_conexant,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec
aesni_intel           376832  8
snd_hwdep              16384  1 snd_hda_codec
crypto_simd            16384  1 aesni_intel
uvcvideo              106496  0
videobuf2_vmalloc      20480  1 uvcvideo
cryptd                 24576  3 crypto_simd,ghash_clmulni_intel
videobuf2_memops       20480  1 videobuf2_vmalloc
videobuf2_v4l2         32768  1 uvcvideo
mei_hdcp               24576  0
rapl                   20480  0
snd_pcm               143360  4 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_core
nvidia              15867904  260 nvidia_uvm,nvidia_modeset
videobuf2_common       77824  4 videobuf2_vmalloc,videobuf2_v4l2,uvcvideo,videobuf2_memops
i915                 3104768  4
snd_seq_midi           20480  0
btusb                  61440  0
snd_seq_midi_event     16384  1 snd_seq_midi
btrtl                  24576  1 btusb
intel_cstate           20480  0
btbcm                  24576  1 btusb
snd_rawmidi            49152  1 snd_seq_midi
videodev              258048  3 videobuf2_v4l2,uvcvideo,videobuf2_common
btintel                40960  1 btusb
input_leds             16384  0
mmc_block              53248  1
at24                   24576  0
mc                     65536  4 videodev,videobuf2_v4l2,uvcvideo,videobuf2_common
ttm                    86016  1 i915
bluetooth             704512  33 btrtl,btintel,btbcm,bnep,btusb,rfcomm
serio_raw              20480  0
rtsx_usb_ms            24576  0
snd_seq                77824  2 snd_seq_midi,snd_seq_midi_event
ecdh_generic           16384  2 bluetooth
joydev                 32768  0
ecc                    36864  1 ecdh_generic
drm_kms_helper        311296  2 nvidia_drm,i915
memstick               24576  1 rtsx_usb_ms
cec                    61440  2 drm_kms_helper,i915
ipmi_devintf           20480  0
snd_seq_device         16384  3 snd_seq,snd_seq_midi,snd_rawmidi
rc_core                65536  1 cec
snd_timer              40960  2 snd_seq,snd_pcm
ipmi_msghandler       122880  2 ipmi_devintf,nvidia
i2c_algo_bit           16384  1 i915
ideapad_laptop         24576  0
snd                   106496  19 snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_seq,snd_hda_codec_conexant,snd_seq_device,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hwdep,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_timer,snd_pcm,snd_rawmidi
fb_sys_fops            16384  1 drm_kms_helper
syscopyarea            16384  1 drm_kms_helper
mei_me                 40960  1
sysfillrect            20480  1 drm_kms_helper
sparse_keymap          16384  1 ideapad_laptop
soundcore              16384  1 snd
mei                   135168  3 mei_hdcp,mei_me
sysimgblt              16384  1 drm_kms_helper
platform_profile       16384  1 ideapad_laptop
wmi                    32768  1 ideapad_laptop
mac_hid                16384  0
sch_fq_codel           20480  9
brcmsmac              700416  0
brcmutil               20480  1 brcmsmac
cordic                 16384  1 brcmsmac
mac80211             1249280  1 brcmsmac
cfg80211              974848  2 mac80211,brcmsmac
libarc4                16384  1 mac80211
msr                    16384  0
parport_pc             49152  0
ppdev                  24576  0
drm                   622592  7 drm_kms_helper,nvidia_drm,i915,ttm
lp                     28672  0
ramoops                32768  0
parport                69632  3 parport_pc,lp,ppdev
pstore_blk             16384  0
reed_solomon           28672  1 ramoops
pstore_zone            32768  1 pstore_blk
efi_pstore             16384  0
ip_tables              32768  0
x_tables               53248  1 ip_tables
autofs4                49152  2
hid_generic            16384  0
rtsx_usb_sdmmc         36864  0
usbhid                 65536  0
hid                   151552  2 usbhid,hid_generic
rtsx_usb               28672  2 rtsx_usb_sdmmc,rtsx_usb_ms
i2c_i801               36864  0
crc32_pclmul           16384  0
i2c_smbus              20480  1 i2c_i801
ahci                   45056  2
psmouse               176128  0
libahci                45056  1 ahci
alx                    53248  0
xhci_pci               24576  0
lpc_ich                28672  0
bcma                   73728  1 brcmsmac
mdio                   16384  1 alx
xhci_pci_renesas       20480  1 xhci_pci
video                  61440  2 ideapad_laptop,i915
```

Comment: I believe the only correct driver is *brcmsmac*. What possibly conflicting drivers are loaded? Please edit your question to show the result of the terminal command: `lsmod`  Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: Be sure to have your wifi router set to a fixed channel rather than auto as the Broadcom Linux drivers don't seem to support the 2.4 GHz channels higher than 11

Comment: How can I do that @Jeremy31 ?

Comment: What channel should I use ? And 20MHz or 40MHz @Jeremy31 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Jeremy31

It was not (directly) about drivers but because of them not supporting 2.4Ghz channels over 11. My wifi was set to 13. It could explain my wifi problems
`Fixed by going into wifi router and setting 2.4GHz channel to 1.`